# How the graphical part is implemented in Linux on Automotive head unit

Tags: linux, java

I have the Automotive head unit on Linux (ext2 filesystem), and I'm wondering how the graphical part is implemented in Linux. 
For example, the background pictures, the buttons, text boxes, text on buttons, text in textboxes, like on the pictures? 
As a .NET programmer, I imagine it as `textbox1.text = "text"`. But how it is working on Linux? Java? Can Java `.class` files contain the graphic images?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you get an answer here unless someone who actually wrote this is a member here :-). Only thing I can offer are some guesses.

You'd usually use some graphics library/framework to do this. [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) is popular because it allows using proprietary licenses, but something this simple could also be HTML + CSS running on some simple WebKit web view based app.

Images are usually simply loaded from disk, but it's also possible to add a base64 encoded image as a string directly to the code.

If you are interested in how GUI applications for Linux are written in general, I'd recommend starting either with [Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstarted.html) (C++ but bindings exist for other languages) or [Gtk](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html) (C but also has bindings to many other languages). Very simple GUI dialogs can be also created using [Zenity](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/3.32/), but this doesn't look like a typical Zenity window.

Comment: Something that simple, they might even be drawing directly to a framebuffer using custom code (potentially using opengl). It doesn't look like they are using windowing so they may not want the overhead of X11/wayland.

Comment: @user1937198 you rare right they are using openGL, because i have found the UIEDRW_drawRoundRect  and more else, also it says that it is gles 1.0 gless as I understand it is opegGL es for embedded systems. uie player is  the name of the mail player of multimedia i guess